# C# Make one expression tree into two (or two new expression trees with divided logic)

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, expression-trees, iqueryable

This question was already answer in the opposite way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028395/c-sharp-combine-two-generic-expression-trees), but reverting the logic is easier said than done.

So let me give you a very concrete example:

I have this :

- e => e.Description == "sum" && e.Summary == "asd"

i want to split this to:

- e => e.Description == "sum"
- e => e.Summary == "asd"

In practical, linq way, i want to archieve this:

```
        var t = list
            .Where(e => e.Description == "sum" && e.Summary == "asd")
            .Take(2)
            .ToList();
```

// To

```
        var x = list
            .Where(e => e.Description == "sum")
            .Where(l => l.Summary == "asd")
            .Take(2)
            .ToList();
```

I know that the result is the same, i want to make them run in separate linq expressions.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "run in separate linq expressions"? This question feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the type of `list` here? Do you really have expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without additional type checking:

```cs
var lambda = // assign first

var binary = (BinaryExpression)lambda.Body;

var lambdaLeft = Expression.Lambda<Func<Some, bool>>(binary.Left, lambda.Parameters[0]);

var lambdaRight = Expression.Lambda<Func<Some, bool>>(binary.Right, lambda.Parameters[0]);
```

Comment: Clean as Freedom. I make it work with reflection. tks man.